# Postgresql select json array into rows and single text

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, object

I have query to get result from table like this:

```
SELECT  test_id, content::json->'scenario'
FROM    test
```

And i got these result, with array of objects in the scenario column:

```
test_id | scenario
29      | [{"name":"OpenSignal", "task":[{"name":"speedtest"}]}, {"name":"ITest", "task":[{"name":"speedtest"}]}, {"name":"EqualOne", "task":[{"name":"flashtest"}, {"name":"web"}, {"name":"video"}]}]
30      | [{"name":"Speedtest", "task":[{"name":"speedtest"}]}, {"name":"ITest", "task":[{"name":"speedtest"}]}, {"name":"EqualOne", "task":[{"name":"flashtest"}, {"name":"web"}, {"name":"video"}]}]
```

The object structure is like this:

```
[{
    "name": "OpenSignal",
    "task": [{
        "name": "speedtest"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "ITest",
    "task": [{
        "name": "speedtest"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "EqualOne",
    "task": [{
        "name": "flashtest"
    }, {
        "name": "web"
    }, {
        "name": "video"
    }]
}]
```

How can i get result like these:

```
test_id | scenario
29      | Opensignal-speedtest
29      | ITest-speedtest
29      | EqualOne-flashtest
29      | EqualOne-web
29      | EqualOne-video
30      | Opensignal-speedtest
30      | ITest-speedtest
30      | EqualOne-flashtest
30      | EqualOne-web
30      | EqualOne-video
```

And

```
test_id | scenarios
29      | OpenSignal-speedtest,ITest-speedtest,EqualOne-flashtest, EqualOne-web,EqualOne-video
30      | Speedtest-speedtest,ITest-speedtest,EqualOne-flashtest,EqualOne-web,EqualOne-video
```

Thanks in advance my brothers

Comment: Its always nice to see what yo have tried. It helps us help you. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: @Mokadillion thanks bro. i have learned that i need to show my script to get maximum help and support from the bros here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your first query, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT test_id, CONCAT(sub.element->'name', '-', json_array_elements(sub.element->'task')->'name') as scenario
FROM 
  (SELECT test_id, json_array_elements(content::json) as element 
   FROM test) as sub;
```

I used a subquery to get the elements from your original json, and then I concatenate the name with each task name with a dash.

Then, to easily get them separated per id, I wrapped it in another subquery using the string_agg function:

```
SELECT test_id, 
       string_agg(task, ',')
FROM(
    SELECT test_id, CONCAT(sub.element->'name', '-', json_array_elements(sub.element->'task')->'name') as task
    FROM 
      (SELECT test_id, json_array_elements(content::json) as element 
       FROM test) as sub
)as tasks 
 GROUP BY test_id
```

Sorry if it looks a bit messy, here is an sqlfiddle link you can use.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fcb27/38

Comment: umm sorry, but there is an error occured with the error message like this: 
"ERROR:  cannot call json_array_elements on a non-array".

i think the error is because my scenario value is not an array type. your sqlfiddle is working because you set the scenario value as text (you add single qoute in the array) and mine dont have the single qoute. how can i cast the scenario into an array?

Comment: you see the type of my content column is json. Adding json is with quotes, like here: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/
I think maybe I misunderstood your data format, though if your scenarios are objects instead of arrays, it should be even easier to process them. Perhaps you can modify the fiddle so that the data has the right format?